# How to Create Folder, File, and Save File in Folder

Tags: excel, vba

EDIT: Wasn't clear enough with my question

```
Sub NewWB2()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim POname As String
Dim lrow As Long
Dim NewfolderPath As String

lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
POname = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lrow, 10).Value 'name I want for both the folder and the document

MkDir "C:\Users\First.Last\Desktop" & "\" & POname 'creates the folder in the path I want
NewfolderPath = "C:\Users\First.Last\Desktop\" & POname ' variable to define that path

Set wb = Workbooks.Add("C:\Users\First.Last\Documents\Custom Office Templates\PO Template.xltm") ' creates from template
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=POName 'Saves file as variable "POname"

End Sub
```

Everything here works. All I need to do is to add a line of code that will save the new workbook in the folder I've created. I can't find how to do this and don't know how to add this in.

Comment: Are you giving the filename an extension? There's a lot of missing information about the value of your variables making it difficult for us to troubleshoot.

Comment: This is all the code that I have. All that I've removed is the destination folder name because it has full name and details. My code currently successfully creates a folder in the right location with the right name, creates a file with the right name and saves it. All I need to add is a line of code to Save it IN the folder I've created, which I can't figure out how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a string example of POname that you are using?
I think you missed a '\' in NewfolderPath:

Try:

```
Sub NewWB2()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim POname As String
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim NewfolderPath As String

    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row 'finds the last row
    POname = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lrow, 10).Value 'name of Folder and File
    NewfolderPath = "C:\destinationfoldername\" & POname

    MkDir NewfolderPath 'creates the new folder with the name defined above
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add("C:\folderwithtemplate\Template.xltm") 'creates new wb from template

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs NewfolderPath & "\" & POname
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry that hasn't been the issue as it creates the folder fine. I changed the path because it had personal details lol. An example for POname would be "PO 123456-789 Example". The folder and new excel file would have this same name.

Comment: Ah, i see, hahaah.
The problem is in the save part of the script, then?
Try this:
`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs NewfolderPath & "\" & POname`

Comment: So just to clarify, this currently creates the folder properly, creates and saves the workbook properly... all I want to change is save the file inside the new folder I've created. I don't have any code for that right now and can't figure it out

Comment: This saves the file in the newfolderPath that you just created `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs NewfolderPath & "\" & POname`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, guess you are missing your Filename:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAS Filename:=NewfolderPath & "\" & POname & "\Filename"
```

if you are using a Variable for your filename try:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAS Filename:=NewfolderPath & "\" & POname & "\" & Filename
```

Comment: I currently have "ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=POname". All this does is save the file with the variable name that I would like. What do I add so that it saves in the new folder I've created and named.

Comment: Please see my new Line, I'm adding the NewfolderPath variable.

Comment: Check out my edited post... I couldn't get that to work

Comment: Please use `Debug.Print NewfolderPath & "\" & POname` and let me know what value is printed in the immediate window.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to do that. I'm now getting "Run-time error '76': Path not Found." and it highlights this line: `MkDir "C:\Users\First.Last\Desktop" & "\" & POname`

Comment: Do you have a C:\Users\**First.Last** folder already created? To use `Debug.Print` just copy and paste the code line in your code, this will show the value of those variables in the immediate Window. You can activate using **Ctrl+G** in your MS VBA window.

Comment: C:\Users\First.Last\Desktop is all created. the folder I create is titled with the variable POName. The Debug.Print value for what you asked is C:\Users\Devyn.Plett\Desktop\POname\POName (actually shows the value of the variable - POName)

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: So good to know!!! Can you please mark my answer as resolve your problem an advice the other guys your question was answered?